# Using raw physical hard disk in virtual machine, with smart capability and true model number seen

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

Is it possible to add an entire physical hard disk to a VM, and inside the VM see the hard disk for what it truly is?

In VMware Workstation 11.1, if I add a hard disk choosing SCSI, with "Use a physical disk", and "Use entire disk", inside, I see the drive as device model "VMware Virtual S", showing it lacks SMART capability.  (If I try adding as a SATA device, I get an "internal error" message that others have  had and VMware has been ignoring for years.)  Even setting the drive as "independent" (although there are no snapshots involved) doesn't help.

In Oracle VirtualBox 4.3.28, if I manually run the command `VBoxManage.exe internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename rawdisk3.vmdk -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive3`, inside, I see the drive as device model "VBOX HARDDISK" with a uuid-looking serial number, showing it lacks SMART capability.

I don't mind using VM software that only runs in a linux host OS.

I don't mind having to use VMware vSphere or anything more advanced than Workstation, if necessary.

Comment: Perhaps if you get a dedicated storage controller card for that drive and then assign that card to a vm...